# Flatten single file directories

Tags: linux

I've spent ages trying to build this and had a good look around for a way to do it. I have a directory tree which contains a set of folders and files. Some of the folders contain more than one file but most contain only a single one.

I'm trying to move all of the files which are on their own in directories one level below the root into the root. E.g:

- Root is: /volume3
- Single file in a sub folder: /volume3/20110103/20110103.log
- File should end up as: /volume3/20110103.log

I know how to flatten the entire structure fairly easily but its the conditional part which I can't figure out how to do. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that by using a small shell script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# go to "root" folder
cd /volume3
# loop over all items in "root" folder
for item in "$( ls )" ;
do
    # if it's a folder
    if [ -d "$item" ] ; then
        # and only contains a single item
        if [ "$( ls "$item" | wc -l )" = "1" ] ; then
            # move all files in the folder to the "root" folder
            mv "$item/"* .
        fi
    fi
done
```

*(untested, but not a problem, since sane people always keep backups)*

Comment: Add `rm -r "$item" after the `mv` line to remove the now empty directory.

Comment: Thanks, that works really well although I ran into trouble with the for loop, found I had to declare **items=$(ls)** followed by **for item in items ;** otherwise it never found anything. This works for me but I realise that if there were spaces in the folder names this wouldnt work!